# Running spark 1.2.0 on ec2?

Tags: apache-spark

I tried building spark 1.2.0 (rc2) and tried to use the ec2 scripts, but it seems not to install spark correctly, is there anything I need to be doing? (e.g. give -v with the hash of the commit in github?)

Comment: Are you deploying to EC2 by specifying the git hash for 1.2.0 RC2 or by specifying the Spark version as 1.2.0? The latter will not work until 1.2.0 is released and certain artifacts are published.

Comment: @NickChammas - thanks, I was afraid this is the case, I'll fork the mesos install script and add my own rc2 pre-built instance as building this from source on each of the nodes is not practical :)